# Should I exclude the Grails Wrapper from my git repository?

Tags: grails, wrapper, gitignore

I've never used the Grails Wrapper before. My preferred method has been SDKMAN so far.

I understand the purpose of the wrapper and basically how to use it. However I have no idea how it works.

Now, I have a couple of questions if I were to use the wrapper

1. Should I exclude **grails-wrapper.jar** and/or **grailsw** from my git repository (.gitignore)?
2. When it comes to a minor Grails version upgrade (let's say 4.0 --> 4.1), should I manually replace any of those files?
3. Is there any difference with upgrading a major Grails version (let's say 4.x --> 5.x)

My questions concern to any version of Grails (3.x, 4.x, 5.x) since the wrapper reinstatement in Grails 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've never used the Grails Wrapper before. My preferred method has
> been SDKMAN so far.

I use SdkMan too, but it serves a different purpose.  Using `grailsw` means that as you switch back and forth between projects which use different versions of Grails, you don't have to reconfigure the environment as you switch back and forth between those projects.  The `grailsw` is configured within the project to use the appropriate version of Grails for that project.

> Should I exclude grails-wrapper.jar and/or grailsw from my git
> repository (.gitignore)?

No.

> When it comes to a minor Grails version upgrade (let's say 4.0 -->
> 4.1), should I manually replace any of those files?

I do.  For many cases the files won't have changed, and when they have, including them as part of the upgrade is simple and should be done.

> Is there any difference with upgrading a major Grails version (let's
> say 4.x --> 5.x)

No.

Comment: So, the relevant part of my **.gitignore** could be like this:

`!gradle-wrapper.jar`
`!/gradlew*`
`!grails-wrapper.jar`
`!/grailsw*`

Comment: In that comment you have included `/gradlew*` which is a separate thing than the grails wrapper.  Be aware that those scripts rely on `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.jar` and `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.